# How do I misunderstand the "super-assignment" operator?

Tags: r, debugging

Working with data.tables, I have a large function `do.everything()` which includes other functions and returns a `data.table`. I run it with:

```
DT.processed <- do.everything(datatable = DT.unprocessed)
```

No error output is produced, but it seems that there is a hidden error somewhere, since after running `first.manipulation()` some NA's are inserted in some variables

```
library(data.table)
first.manipulation <- function(datatable) {
  datatable <- datatable[order(Year)]
  datatable <- datatable[Year %in% c(2001, 2002, 2003)] # for some reason, some NA appear in some variables!
  ...
  return(datatable)
}

second.manipulation <- function(datatable) {
  ...
  return(datatable)
}

do.everything <- function(datatable) {
   datatable <- first.manipulation(datatable = datatable)
   datatable <- second.manipulation(datatable = datatable)
   return(datatable)
}
```

So there seems to be a problem in `first.manipulation()`.

To solve it, I rewrote it so as to export the state of `datatable` before/after each command and determine what causes this "NA insertion" problem:

```
first.manipulation <- function(datatable) {
  datatable.step.1 <<- datatable
  datatable <- datatable[order(Year)]
  datatable.step.2 <<- datatable
  datatable <- datatable[Year %in% c(2001, 2002, 2003)]
  datatable.step.3 <<- datatable
  return(datatable)
}
```

I find out that nor `datatable.step.1` neither `datatable.step.2` has  the "NA problem", but `datatable.step.3` does have the "NA problem". I could not understand why is this happening so I rewrote it as in:

```
first.manipulation <- function(datatable) {
  datatable.step.1 <<- datatable
  datatable <- datatable[order(Year)]
  datatable.step.2 <<- datatable
  print(colSums(is.na(datatable)))

  datatable.step.2.debug.1 <<- datatable.step.2
  datatable.step.2.debug.2 <<- datatable.step.2.debug.1[Year %in% c(2001, 2002, 2003)]

  datatable <- datatable[Year %in% c(2001, 2002, 2003)]
  datatable.step.3 <<- datatable
  print(colSums(is.na(datatable)))

  return(datatable)
}
```

The question is that even after this,
`datatable.step.3` is different than `datatable.step.2.debug.2`.
`datatable.step.3` presents the "NA problem", while `datatable.step.2.debug.2` does not present it.

Why is this happening?

Second, both `print(colSums(is.na(datatable)))`, return `0` everywhere, while clearly there are NAs in the second `print()`. Is this expected?

Last, is it a good practice to use the `datatable = datatable` in the definition of `do.everything()`?
Obviously, I am open to any other recommendations.

Comment: I don't have an answer for your problem, sorry, but if you're programming a whole bunch of functions and putting them inside another by function, you might want to test your individual functions with unit testing, and then do an integration test to know that everything works nice together.

Comment: It's great that you've narrowed your problem down to the `first.manipulation` - even a particular line of the function! (1) Why do you share `second.manipulation` and `do.everything`? They seem irrelevant tor your problem. (2) Why don't you share any data that reproduces the problem? The entirety of this question could be *"I have this data [`dput()` of data or simulated data right before the problematic line], when I run [problematic line] it creates missing values. Why?"*

Comment: As it is, your code looks fine at a glance, but we can't do any testing because you haven't shared any data. [Have a look at how to make a good reproducible example in R](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061).